# Passing parameter to a JavaScript function as a Dictionary object

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight

Please, help me to understand the following part of the code from the post [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit/133997#133997)

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
....
for(var key in params) {
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
}
....
```

Does this mean that we could pass the `Dictionary` object to the JavaScript function (calling JavaScript function from Silverlight app) and it will generate the param string in the form of `key=value&key2=value2&key3=value3` ?

For example, passing the following Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> postdata = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
postdata["productID1"] = 126504;
postdata["productID2"] = 126505;
```

We get the function output: `productId1=126504&productId2=126505` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you mean by output. The function does not *output* anything directly. It creates a form and adds an input element for every key-value pair in the object. It then submits that form, and the browser internally generates that parameter string and POSTs it to the URL. If by output you mean "posts to the server," then yes - that is what it does.

Regarding passing in objects from managed code (silverlight), it seems it is possible. `Dictionary`s will be marshalled to Javascript objects as long as the key is a `string`. You will be able to access the entries by using the regular javascript property notation (`dictionary["key"]` or `dictionary.key`).

[More reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645074%28VS.95%29.aspx) regarding Dictionary marshalling.

Also, I may be wrong (my C# is a bit rusty), but wouldn't:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> postdata = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
postdata["productID"] = 126504;
postdata["productID"] = 126505;
```

be considered invalid? In `Dictionary`s, like Javascript Objects, all keys must be distinct, no?

---

If you just want the query string, coming up with a function to create a parameter/query string from a JS object is relatively easy.

For example:

```
function paramString(object) {
    var strBuilder = [];
    for (var key in object) if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       strBuilder.push(encodeURIComponent(key)+'='+encodeURIComponent(object[key]));
    }
    return strBuilder.join('&');
}

paramString(postdata)
"productID1=126504&productID2=126505"
```

Comment: @rem: If that string is all you want, I've added a function that returns that based on a JS object (or dictionary from SL I guess).

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for your help and for this example, it will for sure give me more understanding of JavaScript. But in my current case I'd like JavaScript function would generate multiple "input" elements in accordance with the number of elements in the dictionary. Like in case for identical "input name" attributes in the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747222/javascript-post-request/3749631#3749631 then I will get in the output required string

Comment: @rem: So you want something to add the input elements to a form, then submit the form, and then return the string? If you submit the form you will leave the page. Would you like to add those to an existing form but do not submit? Please describe what you want in detail so I can help you out.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, Daniel! Yes, I want to dynamically generate the required number of input elements (according to number of key=value pairs in the dictionary), add data to them from the dictionary, and submit (leaving the page). When the form is submitted with that number of input elements, server will get the submitted data in the format "productID1=126504&productID2=126505.." That's all.

Comment: @rem: Oh, well, that's what the function you posted does. The browser will generate the query string internally and send it off with the POST request from the form submission.

Answer (score 1):

Every java-script object is implemented as a dictionary - all properties are name-value pairs. So to pass dictionary to `post_to_url` function, you can use

```
var postdata = {};
postdata["name1"] = value1;
postdata["name2"] = value2;
...

post_to_url(url, postdata, "post"
```

Note that syntax `postdata["name1"]` and `postdata.name1` are equivalent - they refer to same value. You can also use alternate syntax using JS object notation. For example,

```
var postdata = {
    "name1" = value1,
    "name2" = value2,
    ...
    "namex" = valuex
};

post_to_url(url, postdata, "post"
```

Now to answer another part of your question - the sighted JS function will only post the data from params. It will not create a url such as `productId=126504&productId=126505` for GET method. For that, you need to roll up your own version such as

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default, if not specified.
// The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
// It can be made less wordy if you use one.
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", method);
form.setAttribute("action", path);

for(var key in params) {

    if (method.toUpperCase() === "GET") {
       if(path.indexOf("?") < 0) {
           path += "?";
       }
       path += "&" + key + "=" + params["key"];
    }
    else {

       var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
       hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
       hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
       hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

       form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
}

document.body.appendChild(form);    // Not entirely sure if this is necessary
form.submit();
```

}